# Efficient friend suggestion sql query without using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a members table in which every site member is the unique id.
eg

```
id  firstname   secondname  emailaddress    country city    gender
```

the second table is a friends table with the following structure

```
id  meid    friendid    date
```

what query would i use to get friend suggestions of a particular user based on mutual friends and sorted accordingly. before i was using php to loop thru and collect mutual friends but as the site grew, php started misbehaving and running out of memory.

This is the function i was using

```
//-----------------------------------------------    
function getFriendSuggestions($id)    
{
            $friendids=getFriendIdArray($id);  //returns list of your friends
            $networkids=getNetworkIdArray($id);//returns list of all members in your network(friends and their friends)
            $diff=array_merge(array(),array_diff($networkids,$friendids));
            $diff_mutual=array();
            $diff_mutual_total=array();
            for ($n=0;$n<count($diff);$n++)
            {
                $ff=getFriendIdArray($diff[$n]);
                $mf=array_merge(array(),array_intersect($ff,$friendids));
                $diff_mutual[]=$mf;
                $diff_mutual_total[]=count($mf);
            }
            $diff=array_merge(array(),$diff);
            $diff_mutual=array_merge(array(),$diff_mutual);
            $diff_mutual_total=array_merge(array(),$diff_mutual_total);    
            $w=$diff_mutual_total;
            arsort($w);
            $d=array();
            $dm=array();
            foreach ($w as $key => $value)
            {
                $d[]=$diff[$key];
                $dm[]=$diff_mutual[$key];
            }
            $cv=array($d,$dm);
            return $cv;
}
```

Comment: I guess that it based on mutual friends.

Comment: can you post the table strutures?

Comment: Friend's suggestion based on 2nd circle of friends, which means a friend of a friend.Therefore , you'll need to select all those friends and then to check how many friends do they have in mutual to the current member.

Comment: yeah thats what my function posted above does. the problem is that its ineffiecient when the networks grow big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want *"friends of my friends, but who are not also my friends"*.

```
SELECT
  me.id                               AS member_id,
  their_friends.friendid              AS suggested_friend_id,
  COUNT(*)                            AS friends_in_common
FROM
  members        AS me
INNER JOIN
  friends_map    AS my_friends
    ON my_friends.meid = me.id
INNER JOIN
  friends_map    AS their_friends
    ON their_friends.meid = my_friends.friendid
LEFT JOIN
  friends_map    AS friends_with_me
    ON  friends_with_me.meid     = their_friends.friendid
    AND friends_with_me.friendid = me.id
WHERE
  friends_with_me.meid IS NULL
GROUP BY
  me.id,
  their_friends.friendid
```

Comment: this is confusing me, their_friends?, can it be modified to use friends table

Comment: @SirLojik - I use the friends table three times.  And each time I alias it to a new name.  The first time I call it `my_friends` because it is the list of friends related to the row in the `members` table.  The next time it relates to their friends, not mine, so I alias it to `their_friends`.  It's the same table, but used multiple times, so given different aliases.

Comment: Actually there is an error in your query. The 'ON' clause of the LEFT JOIN is wrong. Correct is: ON friends_with_me.meid = me.id AND friends_with_me.friendid = their_friends.friendid

Answer (score 3):

We say that B is possibly-friend of A if there is a large number of entries of the kind

```
(B, someguy) (someguy, A)
```

in the database, and there is no (B, A) entry.

We know the ID of user A and let it be AID. Then we can do:

```
SELECT b.meid, COUNT(b.meid) AS incommon
FROM friends AS b
JOIN friends AS a ON (b.friendid = a.meid AND a.friendid = AID)
GROUP BY b.meid ORDER BY incommon DESC;
```

This will tell us all "possible friends" of A, including those that are
already friends of A. Then we have to exclude them:

```
SELECT maybe.meid, maybe.incommon FROM
( SELECT b.meid, COUNT(b.meid) AS incommon
FROM friends AS b
JOIN friends AS a ON (b.friendid = a.meid AND a.friendid = AID)
GROUP BY b.meid ORDER BY incommon DESC ) AS maybe
LEFT JOIN friends AS already ON (maybe.friendid = already.meid AND already.friendid = AID) WHERE already.friendid IS NULL;
```

Then we need to populate the rest of the fields:

```
SELECT members.firstname, members.secondname, maybe.incommon FROM
( SELECT b.meid, COUNT(b.meid) AS incommon
FROM friends AS b
JOIN friends AS a ON (b.friendid = a.meid AND a.friendid = AID)
GROUP BY b.meid ORDER BY incommon DESC ) AS maybe
LEFT JOIN friends AS already ON (maybe.friendid = already.meid AND already.friendid = AID) 
    JOIN members ON (members.id = maybe.meid)
    WHERE already.friendid IS NULL;
```

This will return friend suggestions for AID, including how many people in common it has for every choice (e.g. "John Doe (15 friends in common)", etc.).

Comment: im goint to try and put both answers to a test and ill be back to vote